# Проблема при обучении сети Sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

```
import sklearn
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
import time
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Ilyas\\Documents\\StrngStuff\\Database2.csv',)
X = df.loc[:, 'PPA-H-AT':'FFA-F-HT']
y = df.loc[:, 'a':'l']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size= .5)
def print_accuracy(f):
    print("Accuracy = {0}%".format(100*np.sum(f(X_test) == y_test)/len(y_test)))
    time.sleep(0.5) 
nn1 = MLPClassifier(activation='relu', solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-1, hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), random_state=0,)
nn1.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

В последней строке выдает ошибку:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-bddabaf72d71> in <module>()
----> 1 nn1.fit(X_train, y_train)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py in fit(self, X, y)
    971         """
    972         return self._fit(X, y, incremental=(self.warm_start and
--> 973                                             hasattr(self, "classes_")))
    974 
    975     @property

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py in _fit(self, X, y, incremental)
    329                              hidden_layer_sizes)
    330 
--> 331         X, y = self._validate_input(X, y, incremental)
    332         n_samples, n_features = X.shape
    333 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py in _validate_input(self, X, y, incremental)
    914         if not incremental:
    915             self._label_binarizer = LabelBinarizer()
--> 916             self._label_binarizer.fit(y)
    917             self.classes_ = self._label_binarizer.classes_
    918         elif self.warm_start:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py in fit(self, y)
    276         self.y_type_ = type_of_target(y)
    277         if 'multioutput' in self.y_type_:
--> 278             raise ValueError("Multioutput target data is not supported with "
    279                              "label binarization")
    280         if _num_samples(y) == 0:

ValueError: Multioutput target data is not supported with label binarization
```

Пример датасета: 4267 строк 12 классов(1-12)

```
PPA-H-AT,PPA-H-FT,PPA-H-HT,PPA-F-AT,PPA-F-FT,PPA-F-HT,FFA-H-AT,FFA-H-FT,FFA-H-HT,FFA-F-AT,FFA-F-FT,FFA-F-HT,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l
-1.2858E-09,5.69975E-08,1.1778E-08,6.77888E-09,-1.86858E-09,1.47961E-08,9.35753E-09,6.93042E-08,-8.77625E-10,2.90068E-08,7.21861E-09,5.02553E-08,"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"
-1.52154E-08,1.46791E-06,2.99663E-07,1.71885E-07,-4.73076E-08,3.79029E-07,2.36769E-07,1.75279E-06,-1.99144E-08,7.36621E-07,1.82945E-07,1.26845E-06,"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"
-1.03324E-08,9.55353E-06,1.9321E-06,1.1053E-06,-3.03847E-07,2.45675E-06,1.52001E-06,1.12487E-05,-1.16288E-07,4.74247E-06,1.17597E-06,8.12735E-06,"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"
1.35356E-06,9.69156E-05,1.93012E-05,1.09928E-05,-3.0159E-06,2.47571E-05,1.50755E-05,0.000111499,-9.60674E-07,4.7261E-05,1.16882E-05,8.03433E-05,"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"
4.48366E-06,0.000218183,4.31577E-05,2.45313E-05,-6.72412E-06,5.5572E-05,3.35998E-05,0.00024844,-1.94702E-06,0.000105561,2.60755E-05,0.000178801,"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"
1.14983E-05,0.000429865,8.44834E-05,4.79299E-05,-1.31264E-05,0.000109186,6.55696E-05,0.000484704,-3.43588E-06,0.000206426,5.09329E-05,0.00034843,"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"
4.88799E-05,0.001274801,0.000247513,0.000139912,-3.82539E-05,0.000322125,0.000190963,0.001410948,-7.96971E-06,0.000603569,0.000148599,0.001011969,"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"
8.74802E-05,0.001994989,0.000385092,0.000217298,-5.93644E-05,0.00050286,0.000296253,0.002188367,-1.08223E-05,0.000938154,0.000230731,0.001567819,"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"
0.000146546,0.002977827,0.000571536,0.000321944,-8.78827E-05,0.000748785,0.000438433,0.003237864,-1.37559E-05,0.001391043,0.000341757,0.002317166,"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"
```

В датасете столбцу с результатом А(PPA-H-AT) соответствует столбец с классом этого результата M(c1), также B~N и так далее.

[image: Датасет]

Comment: Может ли столбец , скажем “c1”, содержать значения отличные от 1? Например - могут ли в столбце “c1” встречаться значения - 3,5,7?

Comment: @MaxU Только в том случае, если столбцу "с1" будет соответствовать результат из другого столбца изначально. В рамках этого датасета, нет не может (в с1 стоят только значения 1)

Comment: что же вы тогда предсказываете - все единицы в столбце "c1", все двойки в столбце "с2" и т.д.?

Comment: MaxU Это данные для обучения. Для проверки данные будут перемешаны, задачей сети является сопоставить данные из X c данными из у, т.к они взаимосвязаны в контексте одного входа из 12 результатов.

Comment: @MaxU, по сути надо рассортировать входные данныые по классам, учитывая их зависимости друг от друга.

Comment: Я пока так и не понял что вы предсказываете... В худшем (самом общем) случае - если в каждом из 12 столбцов могут встречаться все 12 значений,  вам придется "бинаризировать" матрицу `y` таким образом чтобы все значения были либо `0` либо `1`. Т.е. у вас будет 12*12=144 столбца: `c1_1, c1_2, ... c1_12, c2_1, c2_2, ...c2_12, ...c12_1, ...c12_12`

Answer (score 3):

Похоже, в случае мультиклассовой классификации, значения классов должны быть бинарными (т.е. `0` или `1`):

```
In [88]: y_train_fake = np.random.choice([0,1], size=y_train.shape)

In [89]: y_train_fake
Out[89]:
array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

In [90]: nn1.fit(X_train, y_train_fake)
Out[90]:
MLPClassifier(activation='relu', alpha=0.1, batch_size='auto', beta_1=0.9,
       beta_2=0.999, early_stopping=False, epsilon=1e-08,
       hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), learning_rate='constant',
       learning_rate_init=0.001, max_iter=200, momentum=0.9,
       nesterovs_momentum=True, power_t=0.5, random_state=0, shuffle=True,
       solver='lbfgs', tol=0.0001, validation_fraction=0.1, verbose=False,
       warm_start=False)
```

Comment: но как тогда реализовать 12 разных классов?

Comment: @WindWolf, преобразовать данные так, чтобы в `y_train` / `y_test` были единицы и нули - есди строка принадлежит классу `Z` то в соответствующем столбце для этой строки должна стоять `1`, иначе `0`

Comment: извините, но я не совсем понимаю что вы имеете в виду

Comment: что представляют из себя ваши 12 классов? Какую смысловую нагрузку несут столбцы: `a` - `l`?

Comment: Ну, если говорить в общем, то это всего лишь числа от 1-12.
В контексте задания, каждый результат из датасета соответствует результату исследования(допустим исследование -- i, тогда на вход идет[i1, i2, i3, ... , i12] ) Исследований соответственно 12. На выход идет сопоставление результата исследования с самим исследование,м(они закодированы числами от 1-12), т.е i1 соответствует классу 1 и т.д. Так как результаты взаимосвязаны в рамках одного входа, то выходов 12 и они должны классифицировать каждый результат. Столбцы a-l = "1-12", и нужны для разделения столбцов с возможными классами

Comment: т.е. в каждом из этих 12-ти столбцов значения могут быть от `1` до `12` ?

Comment: формально -- да, но для обучения данные с результатами и классы упорядочены, дабы соответствовать друг другу.

Comment: Вы можете привести в вопросе пример из двух строк и 3 столбцов-классов и описать что они обозначают? Иначе не очень понятно получается...

Comment: надеюсь я вас правильно понял. Пример приведен.